# Windows Phone local storage with Azure cloud sync'ing

Tags: sqlite, azure, windows-phone-8, local-storage

I'm writing a WP8 app that needs local storage on the phone itself (due to poor internet connectivity) but also the ability to push to the Azure cloud when there is internet available.

I'm just looking to see what everyone thinks is the best method for local storage?

SQLite? JSON string saved to local storage? Or maybe I'm missing something. Ideally I'd like something that mirrored/used the classes I need that represent the tables in the cloud.

Hope this makes sense.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the local database for Windows Phone, which allows you to mark up your classes with attributes to define the tables, columns, relationships, etc. You can use SQLite, but I prefer this approach since it's straightforward and easy to implement.

Here's the information on MSDN about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx

And this walk through example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx